# Writing Multiple Fields to one textbox

Tags: c#, vb.net, vba, visual-c++

Just need a little help with a program i have been working on. basically i work in a call centre and  i am going to use this to record my notes during calls, i have everything worked out besides on feature. So i when filling out the fields  i need it to show up in a specific textbox, and i need to structure this data to specific lines. I also want to try do this without having to store the data to txt file or a database, i want to try do it all within strings if possible. any help would be greatly appreciated guys.

thanks in advance

Comment: Don't understand this question you've been working on it right so what specifically are you having a problem with ? Also next time try to tag your question correctly I highly doubt this type of application needs all those programming languages.

Comment: what does it even mean. Is it a design problem or a coding problem???

Comment: im having a problem with trying to get all the data from all the fields (textboxes, comboboxes and listboxes) to the one textbox when you click on a copy button, so it is basically grabbing all the entered data from the fields and inserting it into one textbox and structuring it in the process

Comment: If any of these answers helps you, do not forget to mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in short.. you just created a button and some fields and have no idea how to proceed.. try selecting one programming language as @TheKingDave suggested. For example, if you go for C#..

try to read up on the below links to get yourself started:

[system.windows.controls.textbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.aspx)

[system.windows.controls.combobox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.aspx)

but just, if I understand your question correctly, because let's face it, it's far from clear, you want to grab information you added into several textboxes and comboboxes etc and format them into one multiline textbox? If so...

Create a on_click event for your button in which you want to add stuff like..

```
string Example1 = this.mytextbox1.text;
string Example2 = this.mytextbox2.text;
string Example3 = this.mycombobox.SelectedItem;
```

...

afterwards you want to add all these strings together, for example

```
string MyResult = "Example1: " + Example1 + "\r\n" + "Example2" + ... ;
```

and then show this in your resulting textbox

```
this.myresulttextbox.text = MyResult;
```

Hope this answers your question somewhat but I strongly advise reading up on this before going any further..

Answer (score 0):

What is actually your programming language? 
Not sure about your question but if your goal is to concatenate everything into a single string, just read the text value from every *boxes you have and add them into the text value of your destination using a special joker character that is unused in your edited fields like '¤' for example to separate every string. It's easy then to process it later. The brutal way is to hard code every copy. A slightly more refined one would be to have a list of interesting components and for the copy to loop on them and according their type, chose the right access method to get the information.